# Empty GETINPUTSTREAM

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the inputstream from an URL. 
The URL is working fine on browser, so I get the informations needed like this:

```
<SUCCESS>
<STATUS>ok</STATUS>
<OBJECT_TYPE>resource</OBJECT_TYPE>
<OBJECT_TABLE>res_version_business</OBJECT_TABLE>
<OBJECT_ID>206</OBJECT_ID>
<APP_PATH>start</APP_PATH>
<FILE_CONTENT>
UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA5en1zywEAAGMIAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/hABAGRvY1Byb3BzL2FwcC54bWxQSwUGAAAAABwAHAAwBwAAFhQBAAAA
</FILE_CONTENT>
<FILE_EXTENSION>docx</FILE_EXTENSION>
<ERROR/>
<END_MESSAGE/>
</SUCCESS>
```

But while doing this by opening an URL connexion, it does not work.
here is my code:

```
public void sendHttpRequest(String theUrl, String postRequest) throws Exception {
        URL UrlOpenRequest = new URL("http://example.com/docs/modules/content/applet_controller.php?action=editObject&objectType=resource&objectTable=res_version_business&objectId=206");
        System.out.println("UrlOpenRequest: "+UrlOpenRequest.toString());
        HttpURLConnection HttpOpenRequest = (HttpURLConnection) 
        UrlOpenRequest.openConnection();
        HttpOpenRequest.setRequestMethod("POST");
        HttpOpenRequest.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        HttpOpenRequest.setDoInput(true);
        HttpOpenRequest.setDoOutput(true);      


        if (!"none".equals(postRequest)) {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new 
            OutputStreamWriter(HttpOpenRequest.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("fileContent=" + this.fileContentTosend + "&fileExtension=" + this.fileExtension);
            writer.flush();
        } else {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new 
            OutputStreamWriter(HttpOpenRequest.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("foo=bar");
            writer.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("INPUT STREAM: "+HttpOpenRequest.getInputStream().available());
        this.parse_xml(HttpOpenRequest.getInputStream());
        HttpOpenRequest.disconnect();
    }
```

The
 `System.out.println("UrlOpenRequest: "+UrlOpenRequest.toString());` 
is giving me this: 
`http://example.com/docs/modules/content/applet_controller.php?action=editObject&amp;objectType=resource&amp;objectTable=res_version_business&amp;objectId=206`

What can be the problem? Is it an encoding URL problem? If so, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To read the content behind the URL you can do:

```
InputStream input = UrlOpenRequest.openStream();
```

Comment: I used a function to read the content, but it's empty. The problem could the URL itself. Because the `&amp;` is not included in the URL who works perfectly.